Get-WUInstall very slow execution and command hangs
I have ~30+ windows server 2022 servers which connect to internal wsus server.
Wsus gets it updates from microsoft through internal proxy server.
Servers cannot connect to internet on its own.
When I run Get-WUInstall with options then this command is very slow to execute and sometimes even command hangs. I can see that the task scheduler jobs that run this command, those will continue running like several days.
Is this normal behaviour ?
I have tried running Get-WUInstall with options.

I found the issue.
I was using proxy, but still there was this parameter, due to which win update connected to internet.
Make sure this parameter is set to 1.
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate -Name "DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations"

